# Funções em PHP... Como usar?

Tags: php

Para um site foi criado um arquivo php que contem as funções para cálculo de Indice de Massa Corporal (IMC) de uma pessoa no arquivo funcoes.php.

Deseja-se usar essa função na pagina principal (index.php). Qual o código necessário para inserção do arquivo funcoes.php no arquivo index.php?

(Include, import, use, add ou echo ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para importar/juntar código no PHP, há as funções:

1. `require 'caminho/para/seu/arguivo.php'`
2. `require_once 'caminho/para/seu/arquivo.php'`
3. `include 'caminho/para/seu/arquivo.php'`
4. `include_once 'caminho/para/seu/arquivo.php'`

Todas essas funções servem importar código. A única diferença entre "`include`" e "`require`" é que elas tratam possíveis erros de forma distinta.

---

**Em um cenário onde o arquivo que você quer importar não existe, por exemplo:**

Na função include, o código vai continuar a execução, mas será exibido um alerta para o erro no seu site.

Já na função require, será gerado um erro fatal (fatal error) e a execução do código irá parar.

---

As duas variantes das funções, "require_once" e "include_once", significam que o PHP vai checar se o arquivo já foi incluído previamente, e caso sim, ele não será incluído de novo.

Exemplo:

```
<?php  

require 'meuarquivo.php' // Inclui o arquivo
require_once 'meuarquivo.php' // Não inclui o arquivo de novo, pois ele já fui incluído acima. 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Detro do código do `index.php` você deve incluir o arquivo que contenha a função usando o include ou o require.

```
include 'nome_do_arquivo.php';
```

ou

```
require 'nome_do_arquivo.php';
```

Feito isso, é só você chamar a função.